# Solr group result with solrnet 0.4

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am facing Problem with Grouping result data in Solr.

Let me put the data and result which i needed.

[image]

I am using solrnet.dll (0.4) in asp.net. and my code is

```
new QueryOptions
                   {
                       Grouping = new GroupingParameters()
                           {
                               Fields = new[] { "ColourCode" },
                               Format = GroupingFormat.Grouped,
                               Limit = 1000,
                           },
```

Its showing all item but i need RESULT according to screen shot.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you send what is returning?

Comment: @its returning all Items

Comment: Are you looking at the results themselves, or are you looking at the .Grouping property?